# how to clear memory of previous ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I encountered this problem when doing my MCQ Game app testing.

I'm using ARC & Storyboard custom segue and `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"VC" sender:self];` to push from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2` but very seldom popping back the `ViewController1` due to the naturals of the app, moving forward from question to question. the app will become very very sluggish after multiple times pushing. what is the best way to solve the problem?

Custom segue:

```
-(void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceVC = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationVC = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    [UIView transitionWithView:sourceVC.navigationController.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        [sourceVC.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:NO];
                                           }
                    completion:^(BOOL  completed)
                    {     

                        //[sourceVC.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:NO];
                    }                      
                    ];



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed the custom segue from push to pop, based on my view controller name, and it works :)

```
-(void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceVC = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    //UIViewController *destinationVC = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    NSInteger index = -1;
    NSArray* arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:sourceVC.navigationController.viewControllers];
    for(int i=0 ; i<[arr count] ; i++)
    {
        if([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"mainViewController")])
        {
            index = i;
        }       
    }    

    [UIView transitionWithView:sourceVC.navigationController.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{

                        [sourceVC.navigationController popToViewController:[arr objectAtIndex:index] animated:NO];

                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL  completed)
     {     

         //[sourceVC.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:NO];
     }                      
     ];



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is a strong reference cycle going on. Run Leaks to make sure that the previous view controller does not have a strong reference after you push the new one.

Comment: hi Oscar, i dun have any leaks but my allocation will keep increasing.....from 1 mb till 4mb after say 10pushes

Comment: Well, the thing is that because you are using ARC is not actually a leak, it is just the previous VC has a strong reference, meaning it will not get released unless you assign a new value to it, or you set the pointer to nil.

Comment: I tend to refer to those as "semantic leaks".  However since OP is using pushViewController...I imagine they are all getting stored in a navigation controller stack.

Comment: is there a way to fix it, beside changing the value from strong to weak ?

Comment: @borrrden anyway to fix the semantic leaks or the strong references ??
thanks for the reply

Comment: You said it, change it from strong to weak.  However, if they are getting stored in a navigation stack then this won't help anyway.  They will stay allocated until they are popped and not used.

Comment: I had 2 issues with memory leaks. 1 -> I was not removing NSNotification observers properly, 2 -> I did't invalidate NSTimers.